# how to fix the enter function to add a label after pressing enter in text input?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I used `on_text_validate:root.enter()` to use my `enter` function to add a `Label`.

```
def enter(self):
     nl=Label(text='2',pos_hint={'x':0,'y':.2})
     self.box.add_widget(nl)
```

but when i  run the program and i press enter in `Text Input` nothing happening.

How can i fix this problem?

I am not sure this is because `return Box()` does not apply on that function.

code:

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

 

Builder.load_string("""


<Box>
    t1:t1
    l1:l1
    box:box
    BoxLayout:
        id:box
        size: root.width,root.height
        Label:
            id:l1
            pos_hint:{'x':0,'y':0}
            size_hint: (None, None)
            height: 33
            width: 100
            text:'1'
            background_color: 6/255, 61/255, 81/255, 1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:self.background_color
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos

        TextInput:
            id:t1
            on_text_validate:root.enter()
            cursor_color: 255/255, 143/255, 5/255, 0.8 
            pos_hint:{'x':.1,'y':0}
            multiline:False
            height: 33
            width:5000
            size_hint: (None, None)
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            foreground_color: 255/255, 167/255, 167/255, 0.51













""")

class Box(Widget):
    t1=ObjectProperty(None)
    l1=ObjectProperty(None)
    box=ObjectProperty(None)
    def enter(self):
         nl=Label(text='2',pos_hint={'x':0,'y':.2})
         self.box.add_widget(nl)
         
          


class foo(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor='#1618388'
       
        return Box()







if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo().run()
```

Comment: That does add the labels but is not visible due to the longer width of the other widgets. Try making them smaller.

Comment: You are correct.But why does the width of the `Text Input` affect the Label?(since i specified a position for Label)

Comment: Because you used `BoxLayout` as parent widget.